# How does apollo pass arguments to nested field resolvers?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Suppose I have the following schema

```
...

input PersonConcernInput {
   insurance: Insurance!
   minThreshold: Int!
   maxAsset: Int!
}

Query {
   personDetails (concerns: PersonConcernInput) {
       name: String!
       age: Int!
       possessions(minValue: Int!): [Possession]!
       claims(details: InsuranceDetailsInput): Claims!
   }
}
...
```

Sorry for the weird example but it's all I could think of right now. :P

As you can see if I want to query the personDetails, it resolves to two field resolvers each having some input. My question is the data on the PersonConcernInput type has data for both the field resolvers. But how is the data converted or separated into minValue (for possesions field) and details (for claims field).

I don't see how that is achieved.

Comment: it is not, it won't work [without specific, prepared for that, resolvers]

Comment: so how are field resolver arguments supposed to be passed from a parent resolver?

Comment: parent resolver can attach own passed args to returned object[-s], child resolver can check if 1st arg (parent) contains these args

Comment: so then the argument object (2nd one) would be empty in the child resolver in that case?

Comment: yes, if not passed explicitelly

Comment: yes this is what i meant to ask. how do I pass it (from the parent to the child) explicitly for cases when I know there is going to be a child resolver needing some args?

Comment: define separated query variables (with matching types, see docs) and use then where you want ... there is nothing like separate args extraction from main arg

Comment: okay, that makes sense... maybe post this as an answer?